# Google C2DM Authorization Token

Tags: android, python, android-c2dm, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to set up urban airship for my android app, but I'm having trouble getting a Google C2DM Token. 
perhaps, I'm doing this before use C2DM according to Urban Airship Doc.

-Run “clientauth.py” on the command line (located in the “tools” directory in the distribution zip file)

When I run the file on my terminal in Mac OS X Lion, I get this errors.
Could someone help me through this please? Thank you in advance!

```
MacBook-Pro:~ me$ python /Users/me/Documents/ua-android-lib-latest/tools/clientauth.py
C2DM Google Account: my google email for c2dm
Password for my google email for c2dm: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/ua-android-lib-latest/tools/clientauth.py", line 46, in <module>
    ClientLoginTokenFactory().getToken()
  File "/Users/me/Documents/ua-android-lib-latest/tools/clientauth.py", line 34, in getToken
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you spend too much time on this, C2DM has been deprecated. You should use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html). There's a migration guide on the [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html).

Comment: You still shouldn't use it anymore.  That's why they depreciate things, they want you to use GCM now, that's what they're going to support and develop.  C2DM won't be developed anymore, and will eventually be removed entirely.

Comment: I don't believe Urban Airship has released support for GCM yet. You might want to use their proprietary messaging service until they fully support GCM.